# The best approach for optimizing query in large database table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, window-functions

I've PostgreSQL database table named **worker_activity** following structure

```
   Column      |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                        
---------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+
 id            | bigint                         |           | not null | 
 workerName    | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 workerId      | integer                        |           | not null |
 action        | text                           |           | not null |
 created_at    | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |
 updated_at    | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |
```

This table has almost 30 millions of rows and I have the query that creates weekly reports

```
select * from "worker_activity" 
  where "created_at" between $1 and $2 
  and ("action" = $3 or "action" = $4) order by "id" asc
```

So, that "plain" query executes nearly 3 minutes, it's rather slow, isn't it?
How can I speed it up using all features PostgreSQL provides?
Are window functions or some other aggregation method applicable in my case?

Additional info as members pointed out:

- Real row from the table

```
id| algorithmName|algorithmId |action |created_at|updated_at
3 | LiquidityMaker|     1     | {"step_1":{"action":"openOrderSell","orderSum":0.032,"orderPrice":2.3049,"counter":1},"step_2":{"action":"workTime","time":0.03714489936828613}}|2021-07-06 06:49:26|2021-07-06 06:49:26
```

- psql (PostgreSQL) 10.19 (Ubuntu 10.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
- Hardware KVM VPS, 32 Gb of RAM, 8 Core CPU, SSD Drive.

Here is the execution plan:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select * from "worker_activity"
where "created_at" between '2021-07-06 06:49:25' and '2021-07-07 00:00:00'
  and ("action" = 'Start Work' or "action" = 'End Work')
order by "id" asc;
```

```
 Sort  (cost=4138424.27..4138424.29 rows=9 width=903) (actual time=235525.506..235571.749 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: worker_activity_liquidity_maker_1.id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=120287 read=3750619
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..4138424.12 rows=9 width=903) (actual time=235525.494..235571.733 rows=0 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=120287 read=3750619
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..4137423.22 rows=9 width=903) (actual time=235521.443..235521.462 rows=0 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=120287 read=3750619
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_1  (cost=0.00..577947.97 rows=1 width=883) (actual time=30871.374..30871.375 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1532803
                     Buffers: shared hit=493 read=539153
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_2  (cost=0.00..505967.24 rows=1 width=935) (actual time=29927.739..29927.740 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1273284
                     Buffers: shared hit=290 read=473816
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_3  (cost=0.00..409953.82 rows=1 width=978) (actual time=24560.669..24560.670 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 986666
                     Buffers: shared hit=464 read=384922
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_4  (cost=0.00..517571.53 rows=1 width=912) (actual time=30845.683..30845.684 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1328712
                     Buffers: shared hit=602 read=483822
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_5  (cost=0.00..412771.36 rows=1 width=969) (actual time=24726.327..24726.328 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1003528
                     Buffers: shared hit=397 read=387242
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_6  (cost=0.00..505008.02 rows=1 width=950) (actual time=30233.641..30233.642 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1236177
                     Buffers: shared hit=444 read=473533
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_7  (cost=0.00..452042.03 rows=1 width=871) (actual time=26881.948..26881.949 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1215541
                     Buffers: shared hit=516 read=421139
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_8  (cost=0.00..126317.74 rows=1 width=757) (actual time=199.055..199.056 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 389744
                     Buffers: shared hit=116649
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on worker_activity_liquidity_maker_9  (cost=0.00..629843.52 rows=1 width=873) (actual time=37274.984..37274.985 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-07-06 06:49:25'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-07-07 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((action = 'Start Work'::text) OR (action = 'End Work'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1696199
                     Buffers: shared hit=432 read=586992
 Planning time: 0.919 ms
 Execution time: 235571.830 ms
```

Comment: and index on `(created_at, action)` would probably help. Unrelated, but: using `between` with `timestamp` values is a bit dangerous. Better use a range query `>= ... and < ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: can you please elaborate on the dangers of `between`?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: @mustaccio: because it's really hard to get it right with the time part of a timestamp. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d0f2fa1eaa1188f63aa5c035902ae91a And using `timestamp(0)`  makes it even weirder due to the rounding that is applied: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c49ce05f49a05621470cd807dbcda1e

Comment: @mustaccio Thank you for the hint. I've updated OP a bit.

Comment: If "action" is JSON, you shouldn't define it as text.  Looking at the "real row", I'm amazed you know what it will contain ($3 or $4) when querying for your reports.  What are $1, $2, $3 and $4?  What client is issuing this query?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Client is some Laravel PHP code, admin panel backend which generates report file. 
Is it good practice to save JSON directly?

Comment: Where is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `ANALYZE` output has been added.

Comment: @Twissell, 'Start Work' and 'End Work' are clearly not JSON, so you can leave action as text.  You might consider a partial index on (created_at, action) for only those two actions you care about.

Comment: That's plain `EXPLAIN` output. We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Done

Comment: Your table seems to be partitioned, but what is it partitioned on?  Maybe you have the wrong partitioning scheme.

Comment: Your query returns no rows, but we don't know what part of the where clause causes them all to fail, the "created_at"  or the "action" or a collaboration between them. Knowing this would likely give you the answer to fixing the performance.

Comment: Assuming your query really does return rows. The best way of indexing will be on `(action, created_at)` allowing Postgres to do two efficient index scans and joining them together. If `order by "id" asc` is there to provide a top N then you'll want to include it in the index (last) and rewrite the query a little to help it. If you are using partitioning to benefit then you will have to consider where this index fits in (you don't seem to benefit from it directly for this query though).

Comment: You show `action` having JSON data, but your query uses `action = 'Start Work'`. This doesn't add up.

Comment: @jjanes, how can check partitioning?
I'm going to RTFM for now.

Comment: I'd advise you to RTPM instead.

Comment: Also I hope you are not injecting the parameters directly into the query as text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query could be made faster with the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON worker_activity (created_at, action);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but PostgreSQL 10 doesn't  fully support index on partitioned table. Although seems this is only one right solution.

Comment: You forgot to specify the version in your question. When using partitioning, I can only recommend upgrading to a recent release. Anyway, you can create that index on all partitions, and the effect will be the same.